# PostgreSQL: Return auto-generated ids from COPY FROM insertion

Tags: postgresql, libpqxx

I have a non-empty PostgreSQL table with a `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` column `id`. I do a bulk insert with the C++ binding pqxx::stream_to, which I'm assuming uses `COPY FROM`. My problem is that I want to know the `id`s of the newly created rows, but `COPY FROM` has no `RETURNING` clause. I see several possible solutions, but I'm not sure if any of them is good, or which one is the least bad:

- Provide the `id`s manually through `COPY FROM`, taking care to give the values which the identity sequence would have provided, then afterwards synchronize the sequence with `setval(...)`.
- First stream the data to a temp-table with a custom index column for ordering. Then do something like

  ```
  INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2)
  SELECT ttFoo.col1, ttFoo.col2 FROM ttFoo
  ORDER BY ttFoo.idx RETURNING foo.id
  ```

  and depend on the fact that the identity sequence produces ascending numbers to correlate them with `ttFoo.idx` (I cannot do `RETURNING ttFoo.idx` too because only the inserted row is available for that which doesn't contain `idx`)
- Query the current value of the identity sequence prior to insertion, then check afterwards which rows are new.

I would assume that this is a common situation, yet I don't see an obviously correct solution. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out which rows have been affected by your current transaction using the [system columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html). The `xmin` column contains the ID of the inserting transaction, so to return the `id` values you just copied, you could:

```
BEGIN;

COPY foo(col1,col2) FROM STDIN;

SELECT id FROM foo
WHERE xmin::text = (txid_current() % (2^32)::bigint)::text
ORDER BY id;

COMMIT;
```

The `WHERE` clause comes from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/148966/41851), which explains the reasoning behind it.

I don't think there's any way to optimise this with an index, so it might be too slow on a large table. If so, I think your second option would be the way to go, i.e. stream into a temp table and `INSERT ... RETURNING`.

Comment: Fascinating solution, I didn't know about system columns. I went with the temp table solution because it solves some other things for me as well, but I'm sure I will use ```xmin``` for something eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create id with type is uuid.

The first step, you should random your ids  after that bulk insert them, by this way your will not need to return ids from database.